# Python Kivy - Margin to outer layout

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to learn Kivy and am trying to create margins between inner and outer layouts. For the parent layout, the size_hint and pos_hint does what it should, but for the child layout, the margin functionality works only vertically, resulting in the following:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Code:

```
BoxLayout:
    size_hint: [.9, .9]
    pos_hint: { 'top' : .95, 'right': .95}
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: [.8, .8, .8]
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint: [.9, .9]
        pos_hint: { 'top' : .95, 'right': .95}
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: [.6, .6, .6]
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
```

Answer (score 2):

I also think you can use the floating layout.
But I guess that you want to do a design using `padding` and `spacing` here.

The code below will give padding and spacing like the image.

```
BoxLayout:
    size_hint: [.9, .9]
    pos_hint: { 'top' : .95, 'right': .95}

    # Add padding and spacing
    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: 50
    spacing: 100

    canvas:
        Color:
            rgb: [.8, .8, .8]
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size

    # Add New BoxLayout
    BoxLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: [.6, .6, .6]
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
    BoxLayout:
        canvas:
            Color:
                rgb: [.6, .6, .6]
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
```

Image of padding and spacing

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using BoxLayout, it is use to put multiple widget inside one, here you just put a rectangle inside his canvas and give him a child widget, I'm Not sure but maybe it could help, and maybe make the root one a floatlayout.